# Are there any audiobook apps that will remember where you last left off?

Tags: iphone, ios-appstore

As the title suggests are there any apps that will remember where in the audiobook you last left off and pick up from there when you play it?

Also I use the term audiobook here loosely, my books are just mp3 files not ones purchased through itunes or anything. Some of them don't even have meta data that breaks the file into chapters, etc.

So really I just need a simple app that will pick up any mp3 file where you last left off and you should be able to play several mp3 files it will remember where you left off on all of them.

I'm using an iPhone 6S running IOS version 10.3.1

Comment: Plex can be configured in that way

Answer (score 1):

You can use Apple's iBooks app for iPhone/iPad to playback audio books and mp3 files and resume playback. With mp3s you may need to change the "media kind" option from Music to Audiobook in iTunes.

Import your audiobooks or mp3s to iTunes. Select your mp3 file in iTunes, right click and select Get Info from the pop up menu (or just press Command I) to get into the file's properties window. Click on the Options tab then change media kind from Music to Audiobook.

You can then sync your mp3/audiobooks from iTunes to your iPhone if you select to sync manually or sync everything

Answer (score 1):

This question has been simmering for quite a while, but I figured I'd answer.

---

I would recommend [**Bound**](https://itunes.apple.com/app/bound-cloud-audiobooks/id1041727137). I've used it quite a bit, though I don't have much experience with other audiobook apps. It can download audiobooks from cloud storage services (google drive, dropbox, etc..). I use it by dumping all my audiobooks in dropbox and just download a few books at a time and remove them when I'm done. **Being able to download the books is way better than using wifi upload or a cable.**

> Bound can batch download all audio files in a folder in the background. My books, for the most part, are sorted in separate folders and each chapter is in its own audio file.

It doesn't have something like folders to organize book series, but as I only download a few books at a time, it doesn't bother me. Also, Audible's mobile app is the same in that regard so I'm used to it.

[image]

---

I did recently learn about [**CloudBeats**](https://itunes.apple.com/app/cloudbeats-audiobooks-player/id1086480492), which seems to support streaming from cloud services and I guess it did work for one chapter at least... I'm not too sure if I used it right... Seemed a bit difficult to keep track of what was last played and even though I made sure that "resume where you left off" was turned on in the settings, my stream didn't continue where I left off. Has potential, but I think I'll stick to Bound...